# How to map properties from JoinTable to EJB

Tags: sql, ejb, many-to-many, join

I have two objects with `@ManyToMany` relationship between them:

`Person` has multiple addresses. 
`Address` is owned by multiple persons.

The connections is stored in a JoinTable `Person_address` 
There is a property `AddressPurpose` which is stored for each PersonAddress relationship.

My question is - how woult I map this property purpose to JavaBeans? 
For each Address in Person there should be a purpose.

[image]

```
class Person{

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name=FK_person_address, joinColumns = @JoinClumn(name="FK_Person_Id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Fk_Address_id"))
List<Address> addresses;
}


class Address{

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="addresses")
List<Person> persons;
}
```

Comment: your diagram is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to make an own bean for "Person_address".

There is a `@OneToMany` from Person to "Person_address" and  a `@OneToMany` from Address to `Person_address`.